# CSS: Get form label to display on top of form element (jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to get the form label to display on top of each form element. I have the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUgg5/1/) where this is done.

The problem is, how do I get more than one form element per line while keeping its label directly above it?

You can see in my example how I have "city, state, zip" all on the same line, but because of `display: block` in my CSS, it is breaking them up onto separate lines.

```
label { 
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
}

<form>

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br />

    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" /> 

    <label for="state">State</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" /> 

    <label for="zip">Zip</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" /><br />

    <label for="last">Last</label>
    <input type="text" name="last" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A semantic way to markup label/field pairs is to use `DL` list:

```html
<form>
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="name">Name</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></dd>

        <dt><label for="email">Email</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

With this code, you'll also easily achieve presentation you need.

If you need to place multiple label/field pairs horizonally, use separate `DL` for each `DT`/`DD` pair:

```html
<form>
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="name">Name</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="email">Email</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

and use `float: left`, or `display: inline-block` or `display: table-cell` for `DL` (depending on what best fits your needs):

```css
/* Font size zeroed for removing gaps between inline blocks. */
FORM {font-size: 0; }

/* Font size restored for DL. */
FORM DL {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
    /*width: 200px;*/ /* Specify width if needed. */
}
```

BTW, take into account that `for` attribute of `LABEL` element refers to `id` attribute of labeled element, not its `name` attribute.

Comment: I did this, but the label still does not display on top of the input.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on top"? Above by Y axis (in parallel to screen) or by Z axis (perpendicularly to screen -- "layer" index)? DT is always above DD by default -- as any block-level element relative to next block-level element. BTW, you of course can place more than one form element inside same DD.

Comment: For example, go to http://gmail.google.com and the login box shows the labels above the form fields. I am trying to do this while being able to have more than one form field per line, each with its label above it.

Answer (score 1):

please write a css class:

```
.inline-block-display{
display: inline-block !important;
}
```

now add this class to each element which you want to add that to same line,like to this:

```
<input type="text" name="city" class="inline-block-display" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LUgg5/5/)

Comment: inline-block is not a crossbrowser solution (Not what he asked, just saying)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the css 'float' and 'clear'

Have a look at this jsfiddle and you'll understand (Expanded your fiddle)
You can obviously edit the widths to suite your need

http://jsfiddle.net/UxPDR/

like this

```
.small{
    float:left;
}
.clearleft{
    clear:left;
}
```